# Out of def() vs inside def()

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I'm trying to change a column's contents for multiple (5) dataframes. I have the code to do them all individually but it'll look nicer if I can just create a Python function to do it all at once.

Here is the code that works perfectly

```py
dfhome['summary'] = dfhome['summary'].map(lambda x: re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', x))
```

However when I put it into a function like this:

```py
import re
def doSomething2(x):
    x['summary'] == x['summary'].map(lambda x: re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', x))


doSomething2(dfhome)
```

The cell runs, but the column does not change like how it does in the stand alone code.

Basically all the characters such as,'<[^<]+?>' should be gone from the content of the column for each row.

Comment: `=` is not the same as `==`. Why are you using one in one example and the other in the other example?

Comment: On top of what @DeepSpace said I'd suggest you to look at [scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp).

Answer (score 0):

The expression in the function is not an assignment, it evaluates to a boolean value.